# Laravel custom artisan command not listed

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I have several artisan commands which I wrote.
All of them share common functionality, so instead of extending `Command` class, I wrote a `MyBaseCommand` class so all commands extend this one:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SomeCommand extends MyBaseCommand
{
    protected $signature = 'mycommands:command1';

    protected $description = 'Some description';

    :
    :
```

And the base class:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class MyBaseCommand extends Command
{
    :
    :
```

The problem is that from some reason these commands are no longer listed with `php artisan`.

Any idea how can I force laravel to list these commands as well?

Comment: Does `MyBaseCommand` extend Laravel's base `Command` class?

Comment: Can you post some sample code for the base class and one of it's children? Also what do your signatures look like? Also are your commands registered in the commands method or in the commands property?

Comment: @aken-roberts, yes - I have just updated the question.

Comment: @superkevin, I did not register my classes in any place. However, when they extended directly the `Command` class, they were listed.

Comment: @guyaloni you need to register all of your child command classes in the `kernel.php` even though you extend your base command class. Laravel check that file in order to list all of the custom commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite stupid, anyway since it might happen to someone else I leave here the answer:

I wanted to hide the base class, so I had inside it this line:

```
protected $hidden = true;
```

Of-course, the value of this variable was propagated to the high-level class, what made the custom commands hidden.

The solution is simply to add to these files this line:

```
protected $hidden = false;
```

====================== UPDATE ======================

As @aken-roberts mentions, a better solution is simply making the base class abstract:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

abstract class MyBaseCommand extends Command
{

    abstract public function handle();

    :
    :
```

In this case artisan doesn't list it, and it cannot be executed.

Comment: Make your `MyBaseCommand` class abstract, and it won't register as a command.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected $signature = 'mycommands:command1'; //this is your command name
```

Open `app\Console\kernel.php` file.

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\SomeCommand::class,
]
```

then run

```
php artisan list
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unless I extend the classes directly from `Command` (and then I do not need to list them)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel tries to register the commands for you automatically with:

```
/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

You can find this in the `App\Console\Kernel.php`

Make sure that your classes have a `signature` and `description` property.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are missing `use Illuminate\Console\Command;` in the parent class and you have in in the child class @guyaloni

Comment: As far as I know it is not necessary (PhpStorm also tells it is never used if I add it). Anyway, even when I add it I don't see it listed.

Comment: @guyaloni If laravel isn't picking it up by reading the folder you'll need to register it by defining it in the `$commands` array.